# Why my image path different on all android mobiles?

Tags: android

I want to save my image in same path for all mobile phones..here is my code for path

```
if(!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)
{

  File fil = new File(c.getFilesDir().getPath()+File.separator+"HMS_BARCODE");
  fil.mkdirs();

     //and i have created for both external and internal
     //here r the paths coming from mobiles

  String imageInSD = "/storage/sdcard0/HMS_BARCODE/"+ Barcode +".PNG";
  String imageInSD1 = "/storage/emulated/0/HMS_BARCODE/"+ Barcode +".PNG";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `Context` you can use

```
context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
```

you will have storage path: /Android/data/ *packagename* /files/

[Documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String))